# Set state not setting the state

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple component with a single state, I initialize the state when component is created and try to change it when a form is submitted.
It doesn't work for some reason.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class AddTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      submited: false
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    this.setState = {
      submited: true
    };
    alert("Submited state: " + this.state.submited);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="New Todo Description Here"
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Add Todo
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.setState` is a function, so call it like one using brackets ().

```
this.setState({
    submited: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class AddTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      submited: false
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    this.setState({
      submited: true
    },()=>{
          alert("Submited state: " + this.state.submited);
          event.preventDefault();
    });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="New Todo Description Here"
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Add Todo
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) `setState` is a function, but you're assigning a value to it.
The problem is here:

```
this.setState = {
      submited: true
};
```

It should be:

```
this.setState({submitted: true}); // Mind the typo also
```

Just to make a quick note, the React team published react hooks in version 16.8 as a replacement to class components that have some drawbacks. I would give it a try, the docs are [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

With hooks your code would look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function AddTodo() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [isSubmitted, setSubmission] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(event) {
     setSubmission(true);
     event.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-3">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input-group mb-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="New Todo Description Here"
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Add Todo
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```